# SSL certificates configuration query for tomcat APR connector

Tags: linux, apache, https, ssl-certificate, tomcat7

I am trying to move my application from HTTP to HTTPS using SSL certificates. I have configured my Apache httpd conf. file to listen to HTTPS port along with the path where my certificates are placed.

Now my HTTPD process is running fine. I am trying to connect my tomcat server using mod_jk connector. So should I have to mention the same SSL certificates which I configured in Apache httpd conf. to tomcat APR connector in server.xml in order to achieve secure connectivity between them?

Can anyone help me to clear my doubts?

Thanks,
Anshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod_JK usages AJP protocol to connect Apache and backend Tomcat server. You can not use SSL connector in between Apache and tomcat, so Apache certificate is not required at the tomcat level. If you want to use mod_jk application in SSL VirtualHost then simply add JKMount in SSL VirtualHost.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, what you are suggesting is that we don't require a connector setting for SSL if we are using mod_jk ?

Comment: Yes. AJP and HTTP connector is required to handle mod_jk connection at the tomcat level.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it helped me to understand the process.